# nifty mbaas のなりすましPush通信を防ぎたい

Tags: javascript, monaca, baas

現在、monaca(HTML+CSS+Javascript)でモバイルアプリを開発しています。

■最終的な構成は以下を想定しています。 
モバイルアプリ <--> nifty mbaas <--> 自server 
自server上で定期的にプログラムを走らせ、適宜Pushをモバイルアプリへ送るという事を実現させたいです。

■懸念点 
nifty mbaasを使うためには、monaca アプリの中に[クライアントキー][アプリケーションキー]を 
記載する必要がありますが、monaca でビルドしたアプリはunzipすると中身が全て見えてしまいます。

[クライアントキー][アプリケーションキー]があれば、 
REST APIを用いてなりすましPush通信ができてしまうように思えるのですが、 
こちら防ぎ方を教えていただけませんでしょうか？ 
そもそも誤解がありますでしょうか？

■補足 
公式コミュニティ内に↓このissueがあります。

【過去質問】セキュリティ対策方法の相談 #29 
https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/UserCommunity/issues/29

ACLの設定でデータ漏えいは防げることは理解できたのですが、 
Push通信はACL設定が見当たりませんでした。

またcordovaのencryptプラグインでソースコードを暗号化する方法があることは理解しています。 
nifty mbaas側の対応策を知りたいと考えています。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/38272 マルチポストの旨を書かれては。

Comment: @yhataさん
ありがとうございます。

本件、teratailにもポストしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/38272
(先にteratailにポストしたのですが、回答がつかず、こちらにもポストさせていただきました。)

Comment: githubのNiftyコミュニティにもポストしています。
https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/UserCommunity/issues/472

Comment: stackoverflowにポストした旨を、teratail等の質問に追記するべきではないですか。回答しようとする方に配慮すべきで、そういう意志のない質問者には回答も付かないですよ。

Comment: @yhataさん　そのようなマナーがあるのですね。
こういった質問サイト利用初心者で存じませんでした。

Comment: マルチポストで調べてもらえれば、どういう行為か理解していただけるはずです。

Answer (score 1):

こちらで回答がつかなかったため、 
別途、nifty_mbaas公式サイトから質問をしまして 
ご担当者様からご回答いただきました。

公式コミュニティの方に記載します。 
https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/UserCommunity/issues/472

本件、ご興味持ってくださった方ありがとうございました。